# Angular JS - How to overwrite md-menu-content css

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

Im trying to add custom styles to my **md-menu**  -> **md-menu-content**

```
<md-menu md-position="target target">

    <md-menu-content width="4">

        <div>lorem</div>

    </md-menu-content>

</md-menu>
```

Comment: Have you checked Developer tools to see which classes it is using?

Comment: Yup, nothing seems to work, I tried everything except add a class whit JS like you see in this example -> https://github.com/angular/material/issues/5267

Answer (score 0):

Applying the following to the CSS for the codepen example changes the `background-color` of the menu to red.

```
md-menu-content {
    background-color:red;
}
```

**Basic Usage Code Pen Example used to test the above CSS**

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/menu#basic-usage